# Controlling the Back button using onhashchange or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange, jquery-bbq

I need some guidance on how to have very basic control in the use of the back button.

Basically, I need to warn the user that by clicking the back button, when on my checkout.asp page, they will lose the items already there.  I need to instruct them to use the navigation buttons instead.

I've had a look around a have seen mention of the onhashchange event but I could not get it to work.

I also tried the plugin by Ben Alman:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
    // Bind the event.
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Alerts every time the hash changes!
    alert( location.hash );
    })
    // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
    $(window).hashchange();
});
</script>
```

This only fires up the alert (with no value from the location.hash) when entering the page but I simply want to warn the user if they're leaving. If they choose to stay then let them press cancel to leave them on the same page.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return confirm("you have unsaved data. ok to exit?")
})
```

Comment: Diodeus thanks.  I've tried this but again it only alerts when entering the page, not when leaving.  Just to be certain - I've enclosed you r code in $(function(){..code..}) which I presume is correct.  Also, won't this fire even when the user presses one of the navigation button as well?

Comment: Diodues.  That works well.  It does, however, still leave me with the problem that it flags up even if the user uses the 'correct' navigation buttons.  Do you know how I can trap just the back button?

Answer (score 0):

In order to only show a warning when the back button is used, we have to eliminate the alert message when a valid source is clicked.

```
var showWarning = true;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (showWarning) {
    return confirm("you have unsaved data. ok to exit?");
  }
}

function clearWarning() {
  showWarning = false;
}
```

Now just make sure to call the clearWarning() function when an allowed button is clicked. Something like this should work:

```
referenceToElement.addEventListener('onClick', clearWarning(), false);
```

I have not tested this, but I would imagine that something like this is what you need.